# what is ledger space in solana?

Tags: nft, account, ledger, compression, state

[from here](https://docs.solana.com/learn/state-compression)

> On Solana, State Compression is the method of creating a "fingerprint"
> (or hash) of off-chain data and storing this fingerprint on-chain for
> secure verification. Effectively using the security of the Solana
> ledger to securely validate off-chain data, verifying it has not been
> tampered with.
>
> This method of "compression" allows Solana programs and dApps to use
> cheap blockchain ledger space, instead of the more expensive account
> space, to securely store data.

What is a ledger in this context? (I am sure this ledger is not same as Nano Ledger) . I googled `ledger` but always get results related to Nano ledger.

In Solana, the state is stored in accounts (this was the kinda motto of Solana). Now above context mentions `ledger` space. what is it? How can I access it?

Answer (score 1):

In the context of blockchain technology, "ledger space" refers to the storage capacity or data storage available on the solana blockchain network.

Ledger is A list of entries containing transactions signed by clients. Conceptually, this can be traced back to the genesis block, but an actual validator's ledger may have only newer blocks to reduce storage, as older ones are not needed for the validation of future blocks by design.

Solana programs and decentralized applications (dApps) can utilize "cheap blockchain ledger space" for storing data.
This means that instead of using more expensive account space (which may have certain limitations or higher costs associated with it), they can leverage the available storage capacity on the Solana blockchain at a lower cost. This can be advantageous for developers and users as it enables more cost-effective data storage solutions on the blockchain.